# Defining a struct in c

Tags: c, linux-kernel

i have this piece of code

```
struct atmel_tc *atmel_tc_alloc(unsigned block, const char *name)
{
struct atmel_tc *tc;
/* Iterate over the list elements */
list_for_each_entry(tc, &tc_list, node) {
/* Do something with tc */
}
[...]
}
```

this is from a kernel source file, I'm a bit new to C so I'm unable to understand
this line `struct atmel_tc *atmel_tc_alloc(unsigned block, const char *name)`

as so far I've seen structs declared simply as `struct atmel_tc`
without any parameters or * , I've seen usages like

```
struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
}*head;
```

where *head is a pointer to an instance of node. Is something similar going on here as well?

could you explain this line or point me towards some documentation for similar kind of syntax

Comment: That line is not describing the struct.  It is (the first line of) the definition of the function `atmel_tc_alloc`, which returns a pointer to an instance of the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct atmel_tc *atmel_tc_alloc(unsigned block, const char *name)
```

This says that `atmel_tc_alloc` is a function that returns a pointer to a `struct atmel_tc` and takes as parameters an `unsigned` named `block` and a `const char *` called `name`.